# WPF - Custom ErrorTemplate for all TextBoxes in App

Tags: wpf, validation, controls

I have a form with many textboxes, each require the same validation Error-template.
Now, i don't wanna write these validation error-templates for every textbox. So where do i have to put that, so that all textboxes are affected?

**Textbox with Validation.ErrorTemplate:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="23" Text="{Binding User_Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<Validation.ErrorTemplate>
  <ControlTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
      <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

**My CustomControl:**

```
 public class ValidationTextBox : TextBox
    {
        static ValidationTextBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ValidationTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ValidationTextBox)));
            //Validation.SetErrorTemplate(new ValidationTextBox(), )
        }
        public ValidationTextBox() { }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define new Style for TextBox inside a "Resourse" tag of textbox's container. This style will be implemented for each textbox inside container.

Example:

```
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.Resources>
<Style TargetType=TextBox>
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
      <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
</StackPanel.Resources
<TextBox/>
<TextBox/>
<TextBox/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I put it in my app.xaml(Application.Ressources). That worked, thanks! :) The custom control isn't needed.